# How can I show image based on coordinates using php and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, coordinates

I need to fetch some images with their coordinates using PHP and then show them inside a `div` / `canvas` positioned by their coordinates.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "coordinates"?

Comment: I mean x-axis and y-axis.

Comment: I am not sure how you would use the x and y axis.  Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I have image url and position in database which is something like 101,201.The position is x-axis and y-axis . Now I have a canvas or div. I need to fetch those images and show them inside that canvas based on their offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```css
.image{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.image img{
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Wading_moose.jpg" alt="" style="left:-50px;top:-50px;"/>
</div>
```